# Given $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$ converges to $(1-x)^{-1}$ on $(-1,1)$, find a power series that converges to $(1-x)^{-2}$ on $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

How would I go about solving this problem thus far I was thinking to use the Differentiation Theorem or I may use the Power Series Theorem.

I am trying to show the first few non zero terms but not sure if this is the right approach to this question.

Comment: *I was thinking to use the Differentiation Theorem...* - and? ;)

Comment: You were correct.  Differentiate term by term.

Comment: note that $\dfrac d{dx} \dfrac 1{1-x}=\dfrac 1{(1-x)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

As the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

if we sum the derivatives of $x^n$, that is $nx^{n-1}$ we get
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$